# warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*'

Tags: c++

I just started learning C++, and during compilation my code I get an error:

```
main.cpp:59:50: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
     Encryption delta("dragons.txt", "output1.txt");
```

I don't know what this error means, or how to make it work, so if somebody could explain to me why this is happening and how to fix that, I would be very grateful :)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class Encryption
{
    fstream file1; //source file
    fstream file2; //destination file
public:
    Encryption::Encryption(char *filename1, char *filename2)
    {
        file1.open(filename1, ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
        file2.open(filename2, ios::out | ios::binary);
    }
    //encrypts the file
    void Encrypt(void)
    {
        char currentByte;
        bool currentBit;
        int index = 0;
        //sets the pointers to the beginning of the file
        file1.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        file2.seekp(0, ios::beg);
        //reads the first value
        file1.read(&currentByte, 1);
        while (file1.good())
        {
            //loop for four bits
            for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++)
            {
                //finds out if the first bit is a one
                currentBit = (int)((unsigned char)currentByte / 128);
                //shifts the byte over
                currentByte <<= 1;
                //if the first bit was a one then we add it to the end
                if (currentBit)
                {
                    currentByte += 1;
                }
            }
            //writes the character
            file2.write(&currentByte, 1);
            //increments the pointer
            file1.seekg(++index);
            file2.seekp(index);
            //reads the next value
            file1.read(&currentByte, 1);
        }
    }
    //closes both of the files
    void close(void)
    {
        file1.close();
        file2.close();
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    cout << "Welcome to the S.A.S encryption program.";
    Encryption delta("dragons.txt", "output1.txt");
    delta.Encrypt();
    delta.close();
    Encryption gamma("output1.txt", "output2.txt");
    gamma.Encrypt();
    gamma.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change `Encryption::Encryption(char *filename1, char *filename2)` to `Encryption::Encryption(const char *filename1, const char *filename2)`.

Comment: Now i see this main.cpp:11:5: error: extra qualification 'Encryption::' on member 'Encryption' [-fpermissive]
     Encryption::Encryption(const char *filename1, const char *filename2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote what is a [**literal type**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/LiteralType)

> Literal types are the types of constexpr variables and they can be constructed, manipulated, and returned from constexpr functions.

Essentially these are entities that can be used at compile time. Since they are [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr), so for one thing, these are `const`, therefore, read-only. To fix that, you need to change to

```
Encryption(char const* filename1, char const *filename2)
```

Also, you don't need to scope the constructor of `Encryption` class with `Encryption::` since it's defined within the class itself, so just remove that. Else your program won't compile.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Encryption::Encryption(char *filename1, char *filename2)
    {
        // ...
    }
```

Since you don't intend to modify the characters which `filename1, filename2` point to, you should declare them as `const char *`.  Otherwise, informally speaking, the compiler is worried that you might do so, which would not be allowed for a string literal.

Also, since you are defining this function inside the definition of the class `Encryption`, you don't need to restate that with `Encryption::`.  So change this line to

```
    Encryption(const char *filename1, const char *filename2)
    {
        // ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

String literals are `const char[]` types in C++.  Since C++11 onwards, string literals cannot be assigned to non-const `char*` pointers. Doing so would allow code to mutate a string literal's data, which is **undefined behavior**.  This assignment was allowed prior to C++11, for backwards compatibility with C, but it was always discouraged.

If you want to pass string literals to `Encryption()`, you need to change the types of its parameters to `const char*` (or `char const *`) instead:

```cpp
Encryption::Encryption(const char *filename1, const char *filename2)
{
    file1.open(filename1, ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
    file2.open(filename2, ios::out | ios::binary);
}
```

Especially since that is what [`fstream::open()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open) takes in anyway, and you are not altering that parameter in any way:

> ```cpp
> void open( const char *filename,
>            ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in|ios_base::out );
> ```

Comment: thx for help now i understand  how its work :)

Answer (score 0):

As the warning tells you, converting a string **constant** to `char*` - which is not a constant - is not allowed.

The reason for this is that you can theoretically change the contents of a `char*`. But string constants (literals) are read-only.

Therefore you should use `const char*` as parameter type in your method.